# How do I list what is current kernel version for LTS HWE?

Tags: kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

Would like to install *HWE* packages for my 20.04 Ubuntu, not sure if the kernel has been updated or not yet (to which there would be no point in doing for now).

How can I list what version of the kernel would be used by upgrading the *HWE* packages?
OR Where can I find such info?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the exact version of the kernel when you list the dependencies of the package:

```
apt-cache depends linux-image-generic-hwe*
```

will show you what you want to know.

Using the asterisk in the command will make the command independent from the Ubuntu-version used, but also will list the edge-kernel. In your case it will also list the dependencies for `linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04` which exist in the focal main repository.

Comment: Thanks, this `apt-cache depends linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` works!

Answer (score 5):

You can search for `linux-image-generic-hwe` on Launchpad, [like this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+search?text=linux-image-generic-hwe).

Here you can see the `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` branch has a 5.4.0 kernel, while the  `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04-edge` branch has a 5.8.0 kernel.

You can also consult the "[Ubuntu to mainline kernel mapping table](https://people.canonical.com/%7Ekernel/info/kernel-version-map.html)". Here, the latest HWE branch is named "focal linux-hwe-5.8", so I think the Launchpad info is a bit more accurate regarding package names.

As I understand it, the HWE branch will generally follow the latest official Ubuntu release, so as of now it will be kernel 5.8 from Groovy, and as of spring 2021 it will be Hirsute. I also believe the HWE branch is released with point releases, using the following schedule:

- 20.04.1: HWE is 5.4 - HWE-edge is 5.8 (Groovy)
- 20.04.2: HWE is 5.8 - HWE-edge is 5.X (Hirsute)
- 20.04.3: HWE is 5.X - HWE-edge is 5.Y (...) Etc.

Comment: So one should now use the _edge_ variant if you want to use the kernel of current non-LTS, otherwise the HWE would use current non-LTS -1? Also, it does say 5.8 is there in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 as _Proposed_ - what does that mean?

Comment: Yes the edge version as of now. I believe the "proposed" moniker is just that - maybe just an indication that at some point, 5.8 will be rolled into the "main" HWE line, as indicated above.